# How DI works in Spring Framework?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void doSomething();
}

public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    private MyInterface obj;

    public MyClass(MyInterface obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public MyMethod() {
        obj.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I have injected an interface into constructor. How can I make this sample works? How does IoC container realize the interface implementation and allow me to use obj.doSomething? 
I have read docs about Spring but it's pretty difficult to understand.

Comment: When registering the bean class, it looks for its interfaces, and it remembers that for MyInterface, the implementation is provided by MyInterfaceImpl. So when you inject MyInterface into another bean, what is actually injected is an instance of MyInterfaceImpl (or a proxy, if AOP is needed). What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Do I need to use a specific anotation for MyInterface or MyInterfaceImpl? @JBNizet

Comment: It depends on how you plan to register your beans. You can use XML (eek!), or you can use a configuration class with a `@Bean`- annotated method returning an instance of the interface, or you can use classpath scanning and annotate your Impl class with one of the Spring `@Component` annotations. That's covered by the documentation, and the multitude of examples. Time to start reading it.

Comment: Use @Repository in impl class . This will create bean for you. Then use Autowired to access its methods in somewhere in your application

Comment: @SumeshTG Repository is for... repositories. This class is not a repository at all.

Comment: I mean @Repository annotation

Answer (score 1):

Spring need couple things to make DI works as expected, the basic  :

- The bean itself, the concrete implementation (MyInterfaceImpl)
- Where to inject this bean

Your implementation must provide those requirements,

For the first one, and As @JB Nizet you can use either java(`@Component`, `@Repository` ...for instance) or xml approach to make spring aware of the bean,

Where to inject that bean  is a little bit tricky because if you have single implementation of the interface , spring can easily know the underline implementation because the default autowiring is by type technically `MyInterfaceImpl`  is of type `MyInterface` ,(this is pure java interface logic the type of MyInterfaceImpl is `MyInterfaceImpl`   and `MyInterface`both ) then you can simply request spring to inject the bean by using @Autowired

```
@Autowired
private MyInterface obj
```

But if you have more then one implementation, you'll ending by having  two beans of type `MyInterface` and an exception will occur because spring is unable to make the decision which implementation to inject  , and that make sense, to solve this ambiguity you can provide for example `@Qualifier` to make injection by a specific bean name, example [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)